# Image Dispose not working

Tags: c#, memory

I have the following code:

```
 private void picturebox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
   System.Drawing.Image tmp = img[selected].RenderImage(0); //This creates an Image object
   e.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(tmp, movingPoint.X, movingPoint.Y, 512, 512);
   tmp.Dispose();
 }
```

This triggers when the user press PageDown, it basically displays the next image in list.

Now, I see my application memory going up and up and barely decreasing in regular intervals.

Am I disposing the tmp Image correctly? I think that's what is causing my memory issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

tmp = nothing (or null - my VB and c# gets confused)

or

gc.collect()

which will force it to clear.

Comment: I would suggest agains't explicitly calling GC.Collect(). By calling dispose your are signling the GC that the object is no longer in use, in due time when it runs it will collect all the disposed elements.